# How to paint something directly into screen?

Tags: python

How to paint something directly into screen? I dont want to use windows, i just want to print my image directly into screen.
OS: Linux Mint
Lang: Python (2.7 prefered, but 3.x is good also)

Comment: What print? What the heck are you talking about? `print`?

Comment: If you use `ipython`, you can do that in it's qtconsole or notebook

Comment: Do you mean **draw**? Draw directly to the screen?

Comment: I used wrong word. Its "paint" or "draw" of course. I need to throw a bitmap into screen.

Comment: @zhangxaochen:  I want to do it directly into screen.

Comment: @user3340807 then what do you mean by **screen**? make it the screen background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't paint/draw directly to the screen without taking over the whole screen. Like you can't, for example, draw a squiggly line overtop of the Firefox logo.

If you want to take over the entire screen, you can use [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/) and set it to full-screen mode.

```
import pygame, pygame.gfxdraw
import time

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.gfxdraw.circle(screen, 400, 300, 200, (255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()

time.sleep() # otherwise the display will immediately close
```

If you want to use just a single window, you can use any GUI library (like TKinter, PyGTK, PySide, etc.). If you'd like to use pygame, you just do the exact same thing as above, except you remove the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` argument to `pygame.display.set_mode`.

Comment: Actualy i need exactly sth like live overtop of the Firefox logo.
If i cant paint over it, mayby i can at least read the data from screen?